# Powershell: unexpected return value from function, use of $args to access parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters, return-value

Ok, I have coded for quite a while in different, but I am not getting Powershells concept of a function return?....

I am very new to Powershell, so I am sure I am missing something very basic.

I have the function below:

```
function plGetKeyValue ([string] $FileName, [string] $SectionName, [string] $Key) 
{
    if ($PSBoundParameters.Count -lt 2 -or $PSBoundParameters.Count -gt 3  )
    {
        "Invalid call to {0} in {1}" -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name, 
                                        $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ModuleName
        return 
    }

    # Declaration
    $lFileContents  = ""
    $lSections      = ""
    $lDataStart     = ""
    $lStart         = -1
    $lEnd           = -1
    $lFoundSection  = ""
    $lNextSection   = ""
    $lResults       = ""
    $lRetValue      = ""

    # Handle the optional parameter.
    if ( $PSBoundParameters.Count -eq 2  ) {
        $PSBoundParameters.Add('Key', $SectionName)
        $PSBoundParameters.Remove('SectionName')        
        $Key = $SectionName
        $SectionName = $null
    }


    # Read the file in 
    $lFileContents  = Get-Content $FileName | Select-String -Pattern .* 

    # Get the sections.
    $lSections = $lFileContents -match '\[' 
    $lSections = $lSections -notmatch '#' 

    # Start of the data.
    $lDataStart = $lFileContents | Select-String -Pattern "^#", "^$" -NotMatch `
                                 | select-object -First 1

    # We have a section.
    if ( $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey( 'SectionName' ) ) {

        # Find the section.
        $lFoundSection = $lSections | Select-String -Pattern "$lSectionName\b"

        # If none found we are out.
        if ( -Not $lFoundSection) { return $lRetValue }

        # Starting point for the key search is the line following 
        # the found section.
        $lStart = $lFoundSection[0].LineNumber

        # Loop through the sections and find the one after the found one.
        $lNextSection = $lSections | ForEach-Object { 
            # If we hit it, break.
            if ($_.LineNumber -gt $lStart) {
                break;
            }
        } 

        # Set the ending line for the search to the end of the section
        # or end of file.  Which ever we have.
        if ($lNextSection) {
            $lEnd = $lNextSection[0].LineNumber
        } else {
            $lEnd = $lFileContents[-1]
        }
    } else {
    # No section.
        $lStart = $lDataStart.LineNumber

        # Set the ending line for the search to the end of the section
        # or end of file.  Which ever we have.
        if ($lSections) {
            $lEnd = $lSections[0].LineNumber
        } else {
            $lEnd = $lFileContents[-1]
        }
    }

    # Extract the lines starting with the key.
    $lResults = $lFileContents[$lStart..$lEnd] -match "$Key\b"     
    # We got results.

    # Split the value off.
    return $lRetValue = $lResults[0] | Select -ExpandProperty "Line" 
}
```

The process of creating this function has sparked several questions that I have researched and become confused with

1) The documentation indicates that $args should be used to determine arguments.  It never seems to populate for me?  I am using version 4?  As a alternative I used $PSBoundParameters.  Is this advisable?

2) Based on a lot of reading and head scratching, I have found that return values from functions rturn all uncaptured output to the pipeline.  Can someone, please clarify uncaptured?

As an example, I would like the function below to return a string in the variable $lRetValue.  Currently, it is returning True.  Based on that I believe I have something uncaptured?  But everything I am executing is captured in a variable.  What am I missing?

The calling routine is calling the code in the following form:

```
$FileName = "S:\PS\Home\GlobalConfig\jobs.cfg"
$key = "Help"
$section = "Section"

$r = plGetKeyValue $FileName $Key
write-host "r is:  $r"
```

The output shows as follows:

PS C:> S:\PS\Home\Job\Test.ps1
r is:  True

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: 1) `$args` *never* populates? What happens if you do `function test { echo $args };  test "asdf"` ? It doesn't echo "asdf"?

Comment: 2) `$files = Get-ChildItem` captures the return of Get-ChildItem in a variable. If you don't do that, `Get-ChildItem` output goes to the pipeline. If that happens inside a function, they become part of the function return value along with anything else in the pipeline. The `return` keyword isn't anything like other languages at returning a specific value.

Comment: I will experiment further with args and see what happens.  I think I was just purely incorrect nin my understanding of how it worked.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>Terminology note: somewhat arbitrarily, I'll distinguish between *parameters* and *arguments* below:

- *parameters* as the *placeholders* that are defined as part of a function declaration,

- as distinct from *arguments* as the *values* that are bound to the placeholders in a given invocation.</sup>

**Conceptual information:**

> 1) The documentation indicates that $args should be used to determine arguments.

`$args` is a *fallback* mechanism for examining *unbound* arguments in *non-advanced* (non-cmdlet) functions.

`$args` is populated:

- ONLY if your function is *not* an *advanced* function (a function is marked as an advanced function by the presence of a `param(...)` parameter-declaration statement - as opposed to declaring the parameters inside `function someFunc(...)`) - *if decorated with a  `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute*).
- even then it only contains the *unbound* arguments (those not mapped to declared parameters).

In other words: only if you declare your function without any parameters at all does `$args` contain *all* arguments passed.

Conversely, in an advanced function there *mustn't* be *unbound* arguments, and invoking an advanced function with arguments that cannot be bound to parameters simply *fails* (generates an error).

Since defining *advanced* functions is advisable in general, because they are best integrated with the PowerShell infrastructure as a whole, it's best to make do without `$args` altogether.
Instead, use a combination of multiple [parameter sets](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/06/30/use-parameter-sets-to-simplify-powershell-commands.aspx) and/or array parameters to cover all possible valid input argument scenarios.

`$PSBoundArguments` contains the arguments bound to *declared* parameters, and is normally *not* needed, because the variable names corresponding to the parameters names (e.g., `$SectionName`) can be used directly. (It has specialized uses, such as passing all bound parameters on to another cmdlet/function via splat `@PSBoundArguments`).

> 2) Based on a lot of reading and head scratching, I have found that return values from functions return all uncaptured output to the pipeline. Can someone, please clarify "uncaptured"?

Generally, any PowerShell statement or expression that generates output is sent to the *success stream* (loosely comparable to `stdout` in Unix shells) *by default*, UNLESS output is *captured* (e.g., by assigning to a variable) or *redirected* (e.g., by sending output to a file).

Thus, in a reversal of how most programming languages behave, you must take action if you do NOT want a statement to produce output.

If you're *not interested* in a statement's output (as opposed to capturing / redirecting it for later use), you can redirect to  `$null` (the equivalent of `/dev/null`), pipe to cmdlet `Out-Null`, or assign to dummy variable `$null` (`$null = ...`).

Therefore, in a manner of speaking, you can call output that *is* sent to the success stream *uncaptured*.

That, however is *unrelated* to the `return` statement:

The `return` statement does *not* work the same way as in other languages; its primary purpose in PowerShell is as a *control-flow* mechanism - to exit a function or script block - rather than a mechanism to *output* data (even though it can *also* be used for that: with an argument, is *another* way to send output to the success stream).

---

**Diagnosing your specific problem:**

There are many ways in which your function could be made a better PowerShell citizen<sup>[1]</sup>
, but your *immediate* problem is this:

```
 $PSBoundParameters.Remove('SectionName')
```

returns a *Boolean value* that is *sent to the output stream*, because you neither suppress, capture nor redirect it. In your case, since the `$SectionName` parameter *is* bound, it does have an entry in `$PSBoundParameters`, so `$PSBoundParameters.Remove('SectionName')` returns `$true`.

To suppress this unwanted output, use something like this:

```
 $null = $PSBoundParameters.Remove('SectionName')
```

Generally speaking, unless you *know* that a statement does not generate output, it's better to be safe and prepend `$null =` (or use an equivalent mechanism to suppress output).

Especially with direct *method* calls on objects, it's often not clear whether a value - which turns into output (is sent to the success stream) - will be returned.

---

<sup>[1] The following help topics provide further information:

- USE of parameters, including how to inspect them with `help -Full / -Detailed ...`:

`help about_Parameters`

- DEFINING *simple* functions and their parameters:

`help about_functions`,

from which you can progress to *advanced* functions:

`help about_functions_advanced`

and their parameter definitions:

`help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters`</sup>

Comment: *" `$PSBoundParameters.Remove('SectionName')` returns a Boolean value"* - Ohhh!

Comment: Thanks so much for the information and clear descriptions.  I would have never thought of the Boolean from the remove operation being returned!  I guess I need to work with Powershell more and do lots of experimentation.

Comment: @PaulLeDuc: My pleasure. PowerShell does take a while to learn, but it's time well worth spending. Its consistency, comprehensive help system and introspection methods facilitate learning greatly, especially through experimentation.